# Why is the title displaying in the body of the page when using Flask?

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Everything was working fine including the title until I went to add an icon in. Upon manually creating the `<head>` and calling `{{ super() }}` to bring in Bootstrap's black magic, the title now displays above the navigation bar.

base.html

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    {% block title %}{% block page_name %}{% endblock %} - MyFlask{% endblock %}
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
{% endblock %}

<body>
    {% block navbar %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyFlask</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

index.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_name%}Index{% endblock %}
```

Comment: could you include the "bootstrap/base.html" file?

Comment: The bootstrap/base.html file is the standard one that comes with Bootstrap. From what I know, I think it simply contains all the setup and initializations in order to incorporate Bootstrap. This actually might be the file that it inherits (a.k.a bootstrap/base.html), at least something very similar. https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `super()` function in a block, you are adding new contents to that block instead of replacing the original content. So when you called `super()` in the `head` block, Jinja2 inserted the `head` block's content from the `bootstrap/base.html`:

```
  <head>
    {%- block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>

    {%- block metas %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {%- endblock metas %}

    {%- block styles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{bootstrap_find_resource('css/bootstrap.css', cdn='bootstrap')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    {%- endblock styles %}
    {%- endblock head %}
  </head>
```

After that you added a new `title` block, so now you have two of them, and that is the problem.

The solution is easy, don't define a new `head` block in `base.html`, just override the `title` block, and append your favicon lines to the `styles`:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{% block page_name %}{% endblock %} - MyFlask{% endblock %}

{%- block styles %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyFlask</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this doesn't answer your question directly, but perhaps a better way of achieving this outcome is to pass in the page title from the view.

`base.html`

```
{% block title %}
    {% if title %}
        {{title}} - MyFlask
    {% else %}
        MyFlask
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`views.py`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title='Index')
```